# Java array values being overridden

Tags: java

I am just getting started with OOP, and I am trying to create a program that creates an array to store three different types of information, a name, double and an Int.

For some reason, when I run the program and enter the information, it is not stored properly. If I enter, for example, "James", 22.5, 4 on iteration 1, then "John", 23.66, 8 on iteration 2, then print the array, john, 23.66 and 8 prints out twice. I want each iteration of i in my array to store a different set of values, in essence, but I can't seem to figure out why that is not working.

*EDIT TO REFLECT ANSWER

```
for(int i=0; i<boats.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Name: " + boats[i].getName(name) + "  " +
                       "Age: " + boats[i].getLength(length) + "  " +
                       "Length: " + boats[i].getRating(rating) + "\n\n");
}
in.close();
```

** Code for class

```
Public Class file
    public String getName(String name) {
        return name;
    }

    public double getLength(double length) {
        return length;
    }

    public int getRating(int rating) {
        return rating;
    }
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your getters are returning the parameter you are passing in, not the value stored by the setter.

The values in the variables you are passing as the parameters are the last values you input, so you will always print the last values you input.

Remove the parameter from the getter.

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

And invoke like

```
boats[i].getName()
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly and your explanation helped me understand what I did wrong.